# Argument 1 passed to setArchived() must be an instance of bool, boolean given

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this property

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(columnDefinition="TINYINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL")
 */
private $archived;
```

on save Doctrine execute this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function updatedDefaults()
{
    if($this->getArchived() == null)
    {
        $this->setArchived(1);
    }
}
```

but I got this error:

```
Argument 1 passed to setArchived() must be an instance of bool, boolean given
```

how can I set a boolean object in symfony?

thanks

Comment: Can you give us the code for the setArchived function ?

Comment: public function setArchived(\bool $archived)
    {
        $this->archived = $archived;
        return $this;
    }

created using doctrine:generate:entities

Comment: I also tried $this->setArchived(false); same resutl

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with your setArchived method : type hints can not be used with scalar types.
You must remove the bool type :

```
public function setArchived($archived) {
   $this->archived = $archived; return $this; 
}
```

(perhaps you write 'bool' instead of 'boolean' when using doctrine:generate:entities ?)

Comment: no I used @ORM\Column(columnDefinition="TINYINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL"). anyway now it works, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a column type of "boolean"?

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
private $archived;
```

Then in your update function pass true/false instead of 1/0

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function updatedDefaults()
{
    if($this->getArchived() == null)
    {
        $this->setArchived(true);
    }
}
```